# Is there a way to convert a link to a post on m.facebook.com to a link to the same post on full-sized Facebook website?

Tags: facebook

Let's say I use Facebook mobile app and want to get a link for given post, but the app only gives me an opportunity to "copy link"  which looks like the following: https://m.facebook.com/story.php?story_fbid=10153449192633553&id=19292868552

Is there a way to convert it somehow to a link pointing to a post on full Facebook website?
I'm not looking for a certain tool necessarily. Some kind of algorithm will also be fine.

Comment: Just take the "m." from the URL?

Comment: Have you tried it yourself? It does not work. Shows some 404-like error.

Comment: Nope. It was a guess. Note that it was a comment, not an answer. And the question mark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out there is an easier way than suggested in every other answer. It seems that "fbid" is a global identifier in Facebook. Using just it, one can access content it is pointing to like this: `facebook.com/{fbid}`, for example:

`m.facebook.com/story.php?story_fbid=10157028479758918&id=6344818917`

becomes

`facebook.com/10157028479758918` (then the redirect follows)

Answer (score 7):

It's not very intuitive but it's possible.

You'd go to this [Facebook page.](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?fql=select%20permalink%20from%20stream%20where%20post_id%3D%2719292868552_10153449192633553%27) You'll need to be logged in.

In the graph API form field you'll enter

`select permalink from stream where post_id='19292868552_10153449192633553'`

Notice it's the reverse of the elements in your original mobile URL.
`story_fbid=10153449192633553&id=19292868552`

After you run it, you'll get `https://www.facebook.com/FacebookforDevelopers/posts/10153449192633553`

which is the URL to the non-mobile version of the page.

Comment: You can append your answer to state that you can just do `https://www.facebook.com/19292868552/posts/10153449192633553`

Answer (score 3):

remove the `m.` and swap the graph ids like this:

```
https://m.facebook.com/story.php?story_fbid=__PID__&id=__UID__

https://facebook.com/__UID__/posts/__PID__
```